# Does URL optimizations helps in SEO?

Tags: seo, url

Current URL:

example.com/renault-cars/duster/

What is the possibility of gaining an SEO advantage after optimizing above URL to?

example.com/renault/duster

Optimizations:

1. Removed unnecessary "-cars" keyword.
2. Removed unnecessary "/"

Answer (score 0):

SEO friendly urls is a well known concept and indeed helps you generate more traffic and thus increased your site's ranking. This is especially true for auto generated urls which make no sense at first glance. In your case try to format the url in a way that is cohesive and at the same time respects your site's hierarchy. E.g look for something along the lines of `mysite/category/subcategory/thing`.

All in all yes, it is something that will help you.